# How to print out the actual coordinates in a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

How would i make sure that in the 2D array, the coordinates are printed out instead of what is stored? For example if matrix[5][4]="String" i want it to be displayed on the 2D array as 5 4.

Comment: What do you mean by "print out"? You can't really subclass Array so you can't use the [][] notation, but you could certainly have a class wrapped around an Array that implements 2D setters and getters and that has a toString which prints the coordinates. That'd be pretty useless, though, since you could do the same thing by having a routine that prints out an array of coordinates with no object behind it. What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: To read the content of an element in your array dynamically, you would have to use matrix[i][j]. To print out the coordinates, use System.out.println(i + " " + j);